# Camel PropertyInject working example details needed

Tags: properties, apache-camel

I created a class extending RouteBuilder but @PropertyInjector field value is null.
Maven pom.xml has camel-core dependency.
There are some posts that says they got this code working but the code is showing only the
RouteBuilder part. Is there any specific jar to be added or CamelContext.addRoutes() in a particular way to get the injection working?
If there is any github code that contains working example for Camel @PropertyInject annotation please share that link.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly something like this is what you want to achieve?

```
@Component
public class TestClass extends RouteBuilder {

    @PropertyInject("test.name")
    private String name;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:test")
                .log(name);

    }
}
```

The property **test.name** will be something you put in your application.properties file.